# Converting JSON object with Bitmaps

Tags: android, json, bitmap

I have an object which contains a few string members and a bitmap member.

The object is held in a map with a String key and the Object as the value.

I'm using the following code to convert the map:

```
String json = new Gson().toJson(aMap);
```

and then to extract the JSON map I use (passing the above JSON string):

```
Map<String, Object> aMap;
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    aMap = gson.fromJson(jsonString, new TypeToken<Map<String, Object>>() {}.getType());
```

This partially works but the bitmap stored in the object appears to corrupted? i.e. when I try to apply bitmap to an image view I get an exception.

I'm thinking I may need to separately convert the bitmap to a string for JSON but hoping theres a simpler solution, any ideas?

Thanks.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This is actually simple :

```
 /*
 * This functions converts Bitmap picture to a string which can be
 * JSONified.
 * */
private String getStringFromBitmap(Bitmap bitmapPicture) {
   final int COMPRESSION_QUALITY = 100;
   String encodedImage;
   ByteArrayOutputStream byteArrayBitmapStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
   bitmapPicture.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, COMPRESSION_QUALITY,
   byteArrayBitmapStream);
   byte[] b = byteArrayBitmapStream.toByteArray();
   encodedImage = Base64.encodeToString(b, Base64.DEFAULT);
   return encodedImage;
 }
```

and vice versa:

```
    /*
    * This Function converts the String back to Bitmap
    * */
    private Bitmap getBitmapFromString(String stringPicture) {
       byte[] decodedString = Base64.decode(stringPicture, Base64.DEFAULT);
       Bitmap decodedByte = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(decodedString, 0, decodedString.length);
       return decodedByte;
    }
```

This is not mine, I took it from [HERE](http://mobile.cs.fsu.edu/converting-images-to-json-objects/).

Comment: works perfectly, I changed the object to taking bitmap as String and then converted back to image when applying to imageView using above code.